# Java Retrieve Subclass Objects from Parent Class

Tags: java

Is it possible to write a method which allows me to take in a List of objects belonging to a Parent class `Person`.

Under `Person` class, there are several subclasses, which includes `Employee` class.

I want the method to return a separate List which consists of just the `Employee` objects from the original list.

Thank you

Comment: Yes you can, share what you tried, and we'll hep you

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to achieve. Please include a sketch of code at least roughly resembling, how you'd like it to work.

Comment: Do you mean you want to filter a `List<? extends Person>` for instances of `Employee`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do it by steps :

1. Iterate on the `List<Person` to check all of them
2. If the current element is en `Employee` you need to cast it as and keep it
3. Return the list of keeped `Employee`

---

*1. Classic way with `foreach-loop`*

```
public static List<Employee> getEmployeeListFromPersonList(List<Person> list) {
    List<Employee> res = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Person p : list) {                 // 1.Iterate
        if (p instanceof Employee) {        // 2.Check type
            res.add((Employee) p);          // 3.Cast and keep it
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

---

*2. Java-8 way with `Streams`*

```
public static List<Employee> getEmployeeListFromPersonList(List<Person> list) {
    return list.stream()                            // 1.Iterate
               .filter(Employee.class::isInstance)  // 2.Check type
               .map(Employee.class::cast)           // 3.Cast
               .collect(Collectors.toList());       // 3.Keep them
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like:

```
List<Employee> getEmployees(List<Person> personList){
    List<Employee> result = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    for(Person person : personList){
        if(person instanceof Employee) result.add((Employee)person);
    }

    return result;
}
```